# How to use ReactiveMongo streaming with aggregation?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, reactivemongo

I'm using ReactiveMongo.  I want to run a set of pipelines (i.e., use the Mongo aggregation framework) on a collection, and stream the results.  I want to retrieve them as BSON documents.

I've seen examples that suggest something like:

```
coll.aggregatorContext[BSONDocument](pipelines.head, pipelines.tail).prepared[AkkaStreamCursor].cursor.documentSource()
```

This gets me a compilation error because I'm missing an implicit `CursorProducer.Aux[BSONDocument, AkkaStreamCursor]`, but I have no idea how to import or construct one of these -- can't find examples.  (Please don't refer me to the ReactiveMongo tests, as I can't see an example of this in them, or don't understand what I'm looking at if there is one.)

I should add that I'm using version 0.20.3 of ReactiveMongo.

If my issue is due to my choice of retrieving results as BSON focuments, and there's another type that would find an existing implicit `CursorProducer.Aux`, I'd happily switch if someone can tell me how to get this to compile?

So, IntelliJ is telling me that I'm missing an implicit for `.prepared`.

But, an sbt compile is telling me that my problem is that `AkkaStreamCursor` doesn't fulfill the type bounds of `.prepared`:

```
type arguments [reactivemongo.akkastream.AkkaStreamCursor] do not conform to method prepared's type parameter bounds [AC[_] <: reactivemongo.api.Cursor.WithOps[_]]
```

What ReactiveMongo type is available to use for this?

Comment: `Cursor` from aggregate use the same mechanisms as any other cursor, so please first read the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/tutorial/streaming.html#akka-stream) explaining how to stream from cursors. Also trust SBT rather than IntelliJ (which not very good with complex types), and version 1.0.0 has be released since some times.

Comment: I've already imported reactivemongo.akkastream.cursorProducer as the docs suggest.  If I remove the type [AkkaStreamCursor] from .prepared, then I get ```value documentSource is not a member of reactivemongo.api.Cursor.WithOps[reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocument]```.

Comment: Check your code with [examples](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo-Streaming/blob/0.20.3/akka-stream/src/test/scala/CursorSpec.scala#L869)

Comment: Ahhh, so if I use .prepare[AkkaStreamCursor.WithOps], it compiles.  Thanks!  That was not at all clear from the docs.